# Grafana image renderer plugin not working

Tags: rendering, grafana

i have grafana 7.0.5 with image rendrer plugin v2.0
in grafana.ini

```
root_url = http://myServer.com/grafana
```

and grafana is running behind an apache with :

```
ProxyPass               /grafana          http://127.0.0.1:3000
ProxyPassReverse        /grafana          http://127.0.01:3000
```

When i try to render an image of a panle with : [Direct link rendered image], browser wait for about 1 mn and then i have :
[image]

in the log file : i have

```
t=2020-07-08T15:12:46+0200 lvl=info msg=Rendering logger=rendering renderer=plugin path="d-solo/mT2tktqZk/fiche-departementale?orgId=1&from=1594192067086&to=1594213667086&var-liste_dep=All&var-date2_deb=&var-date2_fin=&var-type_et=ETF&var-type_et=ETD&var-type_et=ETVM&var-type_et=ETFR&var-type_et=ETM&var-type_et=ETC&var-type_et=ETT&panelId=6&width=1000&height=500&tz=Europe%2FParis"
t=2020-07-08T15:12:46+0200 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname= method=GET path=/d-solo/mT2tktqZk/fiche-departementale status=200 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=2 size=34727 referer=
t=2020-07-08T15:12:47+0200 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname= method=GET path=/api/dashboards/uid/mT2tktqZk status=200 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=2 size=11580 referer="http://localhost:3000/grafana/d-solo/mT2tktqZk/fiche-departementale?orgId=1&from=1594192067086&to=1594213667086&var-liste_dep=All&var-date2_deb=&var-date2_fin=&var-type_et=ETF&var-type_et=ETD&var-type_et=ETVM&var-type_et=ETFR&var-type_et=ETM&var-type_et=ETC&var-type_et=ETT&panelId=6&width=1000&height=500&tz=Europe%2FParis&render=1"
t=2020-07-08T15:12:47+0200 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname= method=POST path=/api/tsdb/query status=200 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=2 size=927 referer="http://localhost:3000/grafana/d-solo/mT2tktqZk/fiche-departementale?orgId=1&from=1594192067086&to=1594213667086&var-liste_dep=All&var-date2_deb=&var-date2_fin=&var-type_et=ETF&var-type_et=ETD&var-type_et=ETVM&var-type_et=ETFR&var-type_et=ETM&var-type_et=ETC&var-type_et=ETT&panelId=6&width=1000&height=500&tz=Europe%2FParis&render=1"
t=2020-07-08T15:12:48+0200 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname= method=POST path=/api/tsdb/query status=400 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=2 size=1798 referer="http://localhost:3000/grafana/d-solo/mT2tktqZk/fiche-departementale?orgId=1&from=1594192067086&to=1594213667086&var-liste_dep=All&var-date2_deb=&var-date2_fin=&var-type_et=ETF&var-type_et=ETD&var-type_et=ETVM&var-type_et=ETFR&var-type_et=ETM&var-type_et=ETC&var-type_et=ETT&panelId=6&width=1000&height=500&tz=Europe%2FParis&render=1"
t=2020-07-08T15:12:48+0200 lvl=eror msg="Browser console error" logger=plugins.backend pluginId=grafana-image-renderer msg="Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)" url=http://localhost:3000/grafana/api/tsdb/query
t=2020-07-08T15:13:48+0200 lvl=info msg="Rendering timed out" logger=rendering renderer=plugin
t=2020-07-08T15:13:48+0200 lvl=eror msg="Timeout error. You can set timeout in seconds with &timeout url parameter" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin error="Timeout error. You can set timeout in seconds with &timeout url parameter"
t=2020-07-08T15:13:48+0200 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=GET path=/render/d-solo/mT2tktqZk/fiche-departementale status=500 remote_addr="193.41.223.244, 192.168.255.162" time_ms=62022 size=1791 referer="https://sigdca.rct01.kleegroup.com/grafana/d/mT2tktqZk/fiche-departementale?orgId=1"
t=2020-07-08T15:13:49+0200 lvl=eror msg="Render request failed" logger=plugins.backend pluginId=grafana-image-renderer url="http://localhost:3000/grafana/d-solo/mT2tktqZk/fiche-departementale?orgId=1&from=1594192067086&to=1594213667086&var-liste_dep=All&var-date2_deb=&var-date2_fin=&var-type_et=ETF&var-type_et=ETD&var-type_et=ETVM&var-type_et=ETFR&var-type_et=ETM&var-type_et=ETC&var-type_et=ETT&panelId=6&width=1000&height=500&tz=Europe%2FParis&render=1" error="TimeoutError: waiting for function failed: timeout 60000ms exceeded"
```

Can i get some help with this plz, i’m stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error came from the dashboard SQL query, so when you try to render a dashboard with an error in its SQL query it fails rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Provide the values as follows

```yaml
  GF_RENDERING_SERVER_URL: http://myServer.com/render
  GF_RENDERING_CALLBACK_URL: http://myServer.com/grafana
```